# When reading down a column of Excel file, how to define cell coordinates without selecting a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone tell me how to improve this macro?

All the macro does is it just reads an Excel file for a list a accounts to update in an application (SmarTerm Beta).  It technically already accomplishes the goal, but is there a way to code it so that while it’s reading the Excel file, the coordinates of the cells from which to read the account numbers and also the coordinates of the cells in which to write an output don’t depend on a "pre-selected" a cell?  The risk with selecting a cell is that if someone were to accidentally select a different cell while the macro is running, everything will get screwed up.

Here's my current code:

```
Public oExcelObj As Object

Function WaitSystem(Optional NoDialog as Variant) As Boolean
    Dim nContinue as Integer
    Dim nTimeOut as Integer 'In seconds.
    'The default timeout for each command is 3 minutes. 
    'Increase this value if your host requires more time
    'for each command.
    nTimeOut = 10
    If IsMissing(NoDialog) then NoDialog = False
    'Wait for response from host.
    Session.EventWait.Timeout = nTimeOut
    Session.EventWait.EventType = smlPAGERECEIVED
    Session.EventWait.MaxEventCount = 1
    WaitSystem = True
    If Session.EventWait.Start = smlWAITTIMEOUT Then
        If NoDialog Then
            WaitSystem = False
            Else
                nContinue = QuerySyncError()
                If nContinue <> ebYes then WaitSystem = False
        End If
    End If
    Set LockStep = Nothing
End Function

'Establish link.  Search for Excel. 
Function OleLinkConnection
    Const XlMaximized = &HFFFFEFD7
    Titlebar$ = AppFind$("Microsoft Excel")
    If Titlebar$ <> "" Then
        bIsExcelActive = True               
        If AppGetState(Titlebar$) = ebMinimized Then                
            AppSetState 2, Titlebar$
        End If
        Else
            bIsExcelActive = False              
    End If
    If bIsExcelActive Then
        'Create Excel Object using current instance of Excel.
        Set oExcelObj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        Else
            'Create Excel Object using a new instance of Excel.
            Set oExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Version = oExcelObj.Application.Version
    oExcelObj.ScreenUpdating = True
    oExcelObj.Displayalerts = True
    oExcelObj.Visible = true
End Function

Sub JPBmacro
    Dim AccountNumber As String
    Dim Temp As Integer
    Begin Dialog StartDialogTemplate ,,211,74,"Run JPBmacro?"
    OKButton 60,12,92,20,.Proceed
    CancelButton 60,40,92,20,.Exit
    End Dialog
    Dim StartDialog As StartDialogTemplate
    r% = Dialog(StartDialog)
    If r% = 0 Then End
    g$ = "G:\DATA\outputfile.xlsx"
    oleCode = OleLinkConnection
    oExcelObj.Workbooks.Open g$
    oExcelObj.Range("A1").Select ‘<----This selects the cell from which all coordinates are based off of.  The coordinates of oExcelObj.ActiveCell.Offset(Y,X).Value VBA depend on selecting a cell.

    NEXTACCOUNT:
        Temp = 0
        AccountNumber = oExcelObj.ActiveCell.Offset(Temp,0).Value
        While AccountNumber <> ""
            Session.SendKey "CLEAR"
            If WaitSystem = False Then End
            Session.Send "ACTU " & AccountNumber
            Session.SendKey "ENTER"
            If WaitSystem = False Then End
            If Trim(Session.ScreenText(4,6,1,22)) = "INVALID ACCOUNT NUMBER" Or Trim(Session.ScreenText(4,6,1,19)) = "ACCOUNT NOT ON FILE" Then
                oExcelObj.ActiveCell.Offset(Temp,1).Value = Trim(Session.ScreenText(4,6,1,22))
                GoTo RESTARTLOOP
            End If 

            UPDATEIOV:
                If Trim(Session.ScreenText(13,76,1,1)) = "Y" Then
                    oExcelObj.ActiveCell.Offset(Temp,1).Value = "Account already flagged as institutional."
                    Else
                        Session.Row = 13
                        Session.Column = 76
                        Session.send "Y"
                        Session.SendKey "ENTER"
                        If WaitSystem = False Then End
                        oExcelObj.ActiveCell.Offset(Temp,1).Value = Trim(Session.ScreenText(24,2,1,50))
                End If

            RESTARTLOOP:
                Temp = Temp + 1
                AccountNumber = oExcelObj.ActiveCell.Offset(Temp,0).Value
        Wend

    ENDNOW:
        oExcelObj.Workbooks.Close
        MsgBox "All Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see where `oExcelObj` is instantiated? Or how you are referring to a specific sheet.  Regardless of which, (1) you can avoid select by setting a range, ie `Set rng1 = oExcelObj.Sheets(1).Range("A1")` and then use offsets from `rng1`. (2) The user won't be able to interfere while the code is running

Comment: Thanks, brettdj.  I'll try this tomorrow or Monday.

I edited my post above by adding what preceded my code.  FYI, I'm competent enough with VB, but a total newbie with VBA.  So I borrowed the VBA stuff from existing macros.

Comment: @not_a_virus.exe just to add onto what brettdj said, if your VBA code does not rely on using a selected cell, you are much better off avoiding `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet`, and `ActiveCell` entirely.  They are a cause of many headaches in VBA code in Excel.  You can instead reference specific workbook, worksheets, cells, and ranges by name, index, or address.

Comment: @brettdj your comment should be an answer...

Comment: So I replaced "oExcelObj.Range("A1").Select" with "Set range1 = oExcelObj.Sheets(1).Range("A1")".  Unfortunately, the coordinates are still relative so if I click on another cell, the coordinates get shifted, thus throwing the macro off.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.

I replaced all "ActiveCell.Offset(row,column)" with "cell(row,column)"!

Now the macro doesn't get wonky if a another cell gets selected while running.

However, now I realize that if one were to hold the mouse button on a cell for more than a split second while the macro is running, the macro will crash and I get the following error message:

Application-defeine or object-defined error

Comment: Otherwise, I can navigate the Excel file with the directional keypad on my keyboard all day long without any issue.  Is there a way to code the macro so holding the mouse button on a cell for more than split second won't crash the macro?

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep the reference to the first cell?

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = oExcelObj.Range("A1")
i=1
...
x = rng.Cell(i,1).Value

'Or faster yet is reading all the values into an variant array.
Dim array() as Variant
array = rng.Resize(N,M).Value

' Work with array as
x = array(i,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the comment from assylias and that another poster has since "answered" with this approach:

I can't see where `oExcelObj` is instantiated? Or how you are referring to a specific sheet.

Regardless of which,

1. you can avoid select by setting a range, ie `Set rng1 = oExcelObj.Sheets(1).Range("A1")`
   and then use offsets from `rng1`.
2. The user won't be able to interfere while the code is running

Comment: So I replaced "oExcelObj.Range("A1").Select" with "Set range1 = oExcelObj.Sheets(1).Range("A1")".  Unfortunately, the coordinates are still relative so if I click on another cell, the coordinates get shifted, thus throwing the macro off.